# Evaluate a formula in Excel Online only once at file opening?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I had a VB script function `Sub Workbook_Open()` that was copying a value from one cell (a total from previous day) to another cell at file opening. Now I would like to put my Excel sheet online  (MS Excel Online) where execution of VB scripts is not supported so I am trying to realise the same functionality with a formula like `=FUNCTION()`.

Is it possible and how to evaluate a formula only once **each time** at file opening in MS Excel Online (without using VB script)?

Answer (score 1):

While you cannot use VBA in Excel Online, you may be able to use Office Scripts.

This new scripting technology is currently in preview and it also needs to be enabled by your tenant administrator.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/overview/excel

If you don't yet have access to Office Scripts, I'm afraid there is no solution for what you describe.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I voted it up. I didn't know about Office Scripts. Unfortunately my company still doesn't offer this service, but who knows, maybe in the near future. I will go after it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the Online MS Office Scripting is not yet a reality as you can see on [this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/work-with-vba-macros-in-excel-for-the-web-98784ad0-898c-43aa-a1da-4f0fb5014343). Hopefully Microsoft have mercy on us one day and allow us to have this crucial feature for some of our most important workbooks. In the meantime, we shall be using this feature only offline.

Comment: Office Scripts is very much a reality. It's just not available to everybody right now. That's a difference.

Comment: Hello Teylin, 

Thank you for your feedback when editing my last response. I do work for Microsoft in the O365 commercial section as a team supervisor, hence my response was based in what I do and give solutions to on a daily basis. 

I don't understand the reason of your edition to my responses in such a raw manner, I am new to this community and I should be educated in the ways of doing things here but in a nice manner or not at all by all means.